# 'dropped and replaced' ETH still missing

Tags: wallets, uniswap

I have an ETH transaction that is listed as 'dropped and replaced' on Etherscan:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x98640241cd77a4c1301c8522851ec07508ac783239c643a4a3c13b1dc55d9ea1

On Uniswap it shows as pending.

Eth still missing from my metamask wallet.  Transaction is ~10 hours old.  What do I do?